# Hi I am trying to create an insert functionality in Python and Postgres sql as backend

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create an insert functionality in Python and Postgres sql as backend

Below is my code:

```
def insert(car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber):
   conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='Car_Inventory_db' user='postgres' password='password' host='localhost' port='5432'")
   cur=conn.cursor()
   cur.execute("INSERT into carInventory(id,car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber))
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()

   insert("Honda","Civic","2003",'true',"3sdfSKHAN")
```

I have tried various ways, but I get various errors, What I am trying to achieve is that when Insert a value, the id should be auto incremented as I have set it that way. But still gives me an error of non null. See error below

Error

```
File "C:\Users\14168\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\Car_Store\backend.py", line 21, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT into carInventory(id,car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber))
    psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" of relation "carinventory" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Honda, Civic, 2003, true, 3sdfSKHAN).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default value, just omit that column from the insert:

```
def insert(car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber):
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='Car_Inventory_db' user='postgres' password='password' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO carInventory(car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

insert("Honda","Civic","2003",'true',"3sdfSKHAN")
```

Comment: I have tried that also, but unfortunately I get the same error: psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" of relation "carinventory" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Honda, Civic, 2003, true, 3sdfSKHAN).

Comment: You didn't show us the schema.  Does your 'id' column have a DEFAULT clause?

Comment: I dont have a FEFAULT class, as I am not sure how would that work on this situation. DEFAULT is usually used if I want to set a Default value, but in case, there isnt. I wanted to develop, so when i run the insert function, the id should auto increment, inserting the values, passed in the insert function.

Comment: Well, it will only do an auto-increment if you have declared the column to be an auto-increment column.  As I said, you need to show us the schema -- your CREATE TABLE statement.  I'm guessing your column is not declared properly.